# Did a Chinese zookeeper lick a monkey's anus for an hour in order to save its life?

Tags: zoology, china

[This gawker article](http://gawker.com/5907337/zoo-keeper-helps-constipated-monkey-pass-peanut-by-licking-its-butt-for-an-hour) claims that a zoo keeper licked a monkey's anus for an hour in order help it pass an peanut.

> Being too big to pass through the monkey's system naturally, the peanut had to be extracted manually. Apparently, that meant licking it out.

Any truth to this story?

Answer (score 4):

This news appears to be reported from Wuhan Evening News, Wuhan, China, you can see the video [here](http://www.liveleak.com/ll_embed?f=ba0c97ceb987):

[image]

Liveleak.com [reported](http://www.liveleak.com/view?i=4cc_1335953663):

> The 55-year-old teacher zhang help overcome with warm water will a little HeiYeHou bottom clean, and then began to use the tongue keeps licking, has been lick for more than an hour, until the little monkey pull out one peanut. Peanuts from, zhang help overcome this just smiled with satisfaction.

Huffington Post [reported](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/05/03/zoo-keeper-licks-monkeys-butt_n_1475873.html) and said:

> Bangsheng claims the monkey was too small for medication to help it pass the peanut, so licking was the only way to help it -- after washing its bottom with warm water, Orange News reported.

As for as I am concerned, having found that Wuhan Evening News reported this news, it be would be unsound to make conclusion.